# How can I set up parameters in new hue 4 pig editor

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hue

I'm using Hue 4 pig editor and run pig scripts directly from hue. In hue 3.12 we had parameters and there we could add parameter into 2 fields Name, Value

**In Hue 3.12 I could pass**

```
Name=myparamname and Value=myvalue
```

**In Hue 4** I have only 1 field - Parameters with a pattern inside

```
input /user/data, -param input=/user/data
```

But it doesn't work. When I put my pig script parameters into this field e.g.

`YEAR 2018` or `-param YEAR=2018` pig doesn't initialize them at runtime. My parameter YEAR is empty:

```
Pig command arguments :
             -file
             pig-a204.pig
             -param
             YEAR=
```

What exactly should I pass to Parameters field to adjust my script to run using parameters, which are set in hue pig editor?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `'${insert parameter name here}'`. This will allow you to change variable inputs in the Hue editor.